# Why is asynchronous file reading slower than synchronous file reading?

Tags: node.js

I want to read many files (about 30 files), their paths are contained in a string array. I thought if I ran many reading operations at once it will be much faster than sync:

[image: Sync]

[image: Async]

But benchmark shows unexpected results:

**Sync:**

```
  console.time('Sync')
  files.forEach(fileName => fs.readFileSync(fileName))
  console.timeEnd('Sync')
```

> Sync: 0.205ms

> Sync: 0.198ms

> Sync: 0.214ms

**Async:**

```
  console.time('Async')
  const promises = files.map(fileName => fs.readFile(fileName))
  await Promise.all(promises)
  console.timeEnd('Async')
```

> Async: 1.155ms

> Async: 1.05ms

> Async: 1.236ms

What's going on?

Comment: Shouldn't you get one console log result instead of 3 with this code?

Comment: There could be myriad reasons, from the JS engine to OS ordering/buffering. But you're firing off 30 async operations, all doing the same thing on the machine (reading disk), so I'm not too surprised the speedup is minor. The size of the files might also play a role.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Reading in a dir of 30 jpg files totalling 12MB using Node 16 takes ~400ms using the synchronous forEach, and 10ms using Promises.all., so just to confirm: in the second example you're using `fs.promises`, right? Because plain `fs.readFile` _does not return a promise_ so if you're using the callback based plain fs.readFile, yeah your timings are going to be wrong, because your code is plain wrong.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Ooo ooo can you try w/ tiny and giant files too? Now I'm curious (and I bet platform makes a difference, too).

Comment: Steam to the rescue: 630 acf files (each <1kb) takes 3.7 seconds using forEach, and 36ms using promises.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thank you :D Hm, that one is interesting.

Comment: Also, Node can only read files up to 2GB in size (unless you change that. And you never should), so: audio software to the rescue (instrument banks are stupidly big), 10 files totalling 10GB, 13 seconds using forEach, 6 seconds using promises.

Comment: Hmm maybe I should use async when there is more than just 30 files, but for now I'll stop on sync. I will run tests again when there is enough files/lines!

Comment: Maybe, but maybe you should first probably use the correct function calls instead: `fs.promises.readFile(...)`, not `fs.readFile(...)` (or use `const fs = require("fs/promises")`). The part where you're telling node you want the [Promise-based version of the `fs` functions](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_promises_api) is preeetty important if you want to actually test promise-based timing.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I'm pretty sure, this is the promise version of `readFile` because the standard `fs.readFile` will throw an error if the callback is missing (or OP is just ignoring them)

Comment: no way to known unless they show what they used.

Comment: This is dependent on hardware, kernel settings and the file system. Unless you're optimizing for a very specific combination of the three, use async as it will be globally quicker.